# elemento filho tirando o foco do elemento pai

Tags: javascript, html5, onblur

Existe alguma forma de saber quando algum elemento filho está em foco? Meu problema gira em torno do exemplo abaixo onde preciso que uma div não sofra o blur quando um elemento filho estiver em foco (no caso, qualquer elemento do tipo input que sirva para interação com o usuário ativa o `onblur` da div):

```js
(function divShow(){
  var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  div.classList.toggle('active');
  div.addEventListener('blur', function(){
    div.classList.toggle('active');
  }, true);
})();
```

```css
div {display: none}
div.active {display: block}
```

```html
<div tabindex="-1">
  <header>My Tytle</header>
  <content>Hello world!!!</content>
  <footer>
    <button>My button</button>
  </footer>
</div>
```

eu consigo identificar quando um elemento de primeiro nível está em foco e possívelmente fazer um `if` para a ação do blur, mas creio que exista uma maneira mais útil de tratar essa situação.

help?

Comment: Com jQuery é mais simples, você não está utilizando?

Comment: @KaduAmaral, concordo plenamente que com Jquery é mais simples, mas a intenção do trabalho que estou fazendo é utilizar tudo que o javascript pode me fornecer, sem manipular o DOM (por isso estou com Angular). Jquery faz seu tratamento após o carregamento da página, e pesa em questão de tratamento de elementos. =D

Comment: Podes tentar algo com [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), ou com a [propriedade parent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentnode.asp) do DOM.

Comment: estava pensando em algo relativo ao querySelector mesmo mas vi que ia ficar dando inúmeras voltas... obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse é o comportamento padrão, mas com uma condição você pode evitar esse comportamento.

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
div.classList.toggle('active');
div.addEventListener('blur', function(e){
  if (isChild(e.relatedTarget, this) || e.relatedTarget === this) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
  div.classList.toggle('active');
}, true);

function isChild(child, parent) {
  while (child && (child = child.parentNode) && child !== parent);
  return !!child;
}
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
div.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="-1">
  <header>My Tytle</header>
  <content>Hello world!!!</content>
  <footer>
    <button>My button</button>
  </footer>
</div>
```

A condição verifica se o elemento que causou o *blur* (`e.relatedTarget`) é filho ou igual ao elemento que escuta o evento e previne o comportamento padrão com `event.preventDefault()`;

Resultado esperado: ao clicar sobre qualquer elemento da `<div>` ele continua visível, ao clicar fora ela é ocultada.

Comment: excelente, obrigado, funcionou 100% na minha solução